# Por que não sou notificado quando uma pergunta minha é fechada?

Tags: novo-recurso, perguntas-fechadas

Só percebemos que uma pergunta nossa foi fechada quando a abrimos por algum motivo, e vemos o aviso *"Pendente..."* ou *"Fechada..."*.

Não seria o correto sermos notificados do fechamento das perguntas as quais sou o *"[dono](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/6038/66203)"*?

Comment: +1 concordo plenamente.

Answer (score 2):

Creio que não.

Perguntas são marcadas como pendentes quando possuem formato ou conteúdo inadequado para o site. Se isso ocorre, é porque a pessoa não se deu ao trabalho de [fazer o *tour*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour), [RTFM](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help) e tirar dúvidas aqui no Meta.

Se a pessoa é analdidata e não se dá ao trabalho mínimo de fazer as coisas que eu mencionei acima, então ter que correr atrás de suas perguntas é um excelente exercício. Assim, ou a pessoa aprende na experiência a publicar conteúdo dentro dos padrões do site, ou ela naturalmente deixa de fazer publicações por aqui. O primeiro caso é certamente melhor. O segundo caso é discutível, mas acredito que se a pessoa vai sempre gerar mais ruído do que conteúdo, o melhor é que não precisemos lidar com o ruído de qualquer forma.

Note que isso não é um padrão absoluto - acredito que todo mundo já cometeu seus deslizes antes de entrar no espírito da coisa. E em geral quem não apanhou aqui é porque já tinha apanhado antes no SO em inglês.