# Eu sou dono do meu conteudo?

Tags: suporte, comportamento, licença

Estava fazendo uma limpa em minhas perguntas antigas e sem resposta, e que julguei serem específicas demais para serem respondidas.

Eis que recebo esta mensagem :

> [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Após isso refleti um pouco e me surgiu algumas questões.

#### Questões

- Se as Perguntas/Respostas são de minha autoria eu sou "dono" delas?
- Porque existe um limite de remoção?
- Se existe um limite de remoção para o caso que minha conta ser roubada e alguém estar fazendo mal uso dela. Seria possível restaurar tudo que foi perdido?

#### Adendo

- Lembrando que caso eu queira abrir mão da autoria eu posso alterar para "wiki da comunidade". Isso não seria o mesmo que abrir mão de ser "dono"?

Comment: Ótimas perguntas, tem que elaborar cada ponto para responder melhor, mas de forma resumida: Não, você não é o dono: https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/

Comment: Relacionadas: [Oh, não! Editaram minha pergunta!](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2212/3117), [Licença MIT – Como utilizar códigos do Stack Overflow](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4685/3117)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

De acordo com os [termos de uso](https://stackexchange.com/legal) você não é dono do seu conteúdo. Você é apenas o autor. São coisas diferentes.

Conforme pode ser visto no rodapé a licença automaticamente usada para o conteúdo postado aqui é Creative Commons Attribution-ShareAlike (CC BY-SA), e [a versão varia de acordo com a data em que o conteúdo foi postado](https://stackoverflow.com/help/licensing).

Apagar algo seu pode ser considerado vandalismo em algumas circunstâncias, já que está apagando um conteúdo da comunidade que você foi o autor. Não em todas, claro. O limite existe para evitar o abuso.

Se há algum problema pontual é só arrumar. Se não quer estar vinculado com o conteúdo pode pedir para anonimizá-lo. Mas apagar o que pode ser útil para outras pessoas não pode.

É possível restaurar tudo sim até porque não é apagado de fato, só é escondido. Logo você poderá ver tudo o que fica escondido, não só as suas (10k).

Mudar para Wiki não abre mão da autoria, apenas disfarça um pouco já que só fica visível o último que editou e o histórico de todos autores fica no *link* que mostra as edições feitas no *post*. Só a SE pode anonimizar de fato.

Comment: Como seria o processo para "anonimizá-lo"?

Comment: Pedir para a SE em https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/contact ou pedir para um moderador cuidar disto, acho que pode só sinalizar.

Answer (score 11):

Você recebe o crédito pela resposta/pergunta mas o "dono" é o site (SE).

> Se existe um limite de remoção para o caso que minha conta ser roubada e alguém estar fazendo mal uso dela. Seria possível restaurar tudo que foi perdido?

Sim é possível restaurar todas as postagem exceto comentários.

Relacionado:

[Stack Overflow e o Código-Fonte](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4525/91)